# bootstrap form-inline to display fields in one row

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want my sign in form to display the fields in a row next to each other instead of under each other.

header:

Update: this code works now

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <%= link_to "Apollo", root_path, id: "logo" %>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">

<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, :html => { :class => "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
  <input id="session_email" name="session[email]" type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Email">
  <input id="session_password" name="session[password]" type="password" class="input-medium" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Sign in</button>
<% end %>

</ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Generated HTML

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <a href="/" id="logo">Apollo</a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="span2 offset3">
              <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="xmS0FBX+pX8ZzBr/yHIUNmXOQMFI4krsv3FxIl51Hjg=" /></div>

                  <input id="session_email" name="session[email]" placeholder="Email" size="30" type="text" />

                  <input id="session_password" name="session[password]" placeholder="Password" size="30" type="password" />

                  <input class="btn btn-small btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />

</form>                </div>
          </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Custom CSS.SCSS

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your CSS.

It's not a problem with the [view](http://jsfiddle.net/7jsJd/).

It looks like you're using bootstrap, so add the class `.form-inline` to the form:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, :html => { :class => "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: It's something in your CSS. Updated answer.

Comment: still no solution I posed the CSS trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Each `input` element within the form should be displayed inline or inline-block, and should be sized to fit all the elements on a single line. Any overflow will be bumped down to the next line.

Give the form a class. For example, `inline_form`.

```
form.inline_form input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px; //small for example
}
```

[Example using your code](http://jsfiddle.net/4epf5/)